# I am trying to apply a python code to all the files in a directory but it gives me a error

Tags: python, css, json, numpy

I am trying to apply a python code to all the files in a directory but it gives me a error:

```
test_image = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1],0)
   IndexError: list index out of range
```

I dont know what to change I tried few things but it does not help so if someone can help with this that would be great.  And using stackoverflow for the first time, just to see how it works.

```
import sys
import cv2
import os
import numpy as np
from utils import pointsInsideCircle, compare, zigzag
from math import pi as PI

filepath = os.path.join("/Users/ssm/Desktop/X/1/Original Images",     "*.tif")
W   = 8             #block size for comparision
Dsim    = 0.1           #threshold for symmetry
Nd  = 25            #nearest block

quadrants_points = pointsInsideCircle(W/4)  #(i,j) position of blocks      which are partially/completely inside circle of radius W/2
zigzag_points = zigzag(W/2)
test_image = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1],0)
height,width = test_image.shape[:2]
#print (height,width)
vectors_list = []
for j in range(0,height-W+1):
    for i in range(0,width-W+1):
        block = test_image[j:j+W,i:i+W]
        dct_block =  cv2.dct(np.float32(block))
        feature_block = [[],[],[],[]]
        for index,coeff_list in enumerate(zigzag_points):
            for coeff in coeff_list:
                 feature_block[index].append(dct_block[coeff[0],coeff[1]])

        feature_block_np = np.array(feature_block)

        feature_vector = []
        for quadrant,points in quadrants_points.iteritems():
            summ = 0
        for point in points:
            summ = summ + feature_block_np[point[0],point[1]]
        feature_vector.append(summ/PI)
    vectors_list.append(np.array(feature_vector))

vectors_list2 = cv2.sort(np.array(vectors_list),cv2.SORT_EVERY_ROW)
print "vectors calculated"
import json
with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
    json.dump(vectors_list2.tolist(), outfile)


i=0
blocks = []
for i in range(0,len(vectors_list)):
    if i%width == 0:
        print i/width
    posA = [i/width,i%width]
    j = i+1
    for j in range(i+1,len(vectors_list)):
        posB = [j/width,j%width]
        if compare(vectors_list[i],vectors_list[j],posA,posB,Dsim,Nd):
            print (posA,posB)
            blocks.append([posA,posB])

output_image = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1],1)
for block in blocks:
    x1 = block[0][0]
    x1_8 = block[0][0]+W
    y1 = block[0][1]
    y1_8 = block[0][1]+W

    output_image[x1:x1_8,y1:y1_8] = [0,0,255]

    x2 = block[1][0]
    x2_8 = block[1][0]+W
    y2 = block[1][1]
    y2_8 = block[1][1]+W

    output_image[x2:x2_8,y2:y2_8]=[0,255,0]

cv2.imwrite("output.jpg",output_image)


print "feature vectors extracted"
```

Comment: What arguments are you passing to it when you run it?

Comment: which line is throwing the error?

Comment: Also the "for i  in range" and "for j in range", you don't need to start by saying "i = 0" and "j = i + 1"  - that's being accomplished in your range argument.

Comment: line 15, in <module>
    test_image = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1],0)
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: So shall I Just remove that @mauve

Comment: @Sina removing those assignments will not change anything. And your problem is in that line - check the length of sys.argv.

Answer (score 0):

```
test_image = cv2.imread(sys.argv[1],0)
```

is checking the list provided by the commandline for a file name.  For example if you invoked this script with:

```
$python myprog.py afilename.xxx
```

`sys.argv` would be `['myprog', 'afilename.xxx']`, and this `imread` line would load an image from `afilename.xxx`.

If you don't provide that filename, `sys.argv` will only have the script name, and `sys.argv[1]` will raise this error.

Comment: I just tried to run it in the terminal as python /Users/ssm/Desktop/image-forgery-detection-master/Yanjun-Tiegang/algo.py /Users/ssm/Desktop/X/1/Original\ Images/*.tif  and did read .with the original code (https://github.com/dewgeek/image-forgery-detection/blob/master/Yanjun-Tiegang/algo.py)

Comment: But it takes for ever, even on a GPU

Comment: Without getting into details I see several loops that probably slow you down.  For example the double loop of the `feature_block`.  But I don't know your problem well enough to suggest improvements.